# How to execute a shell command from a "starter"?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, run-dialog

I would like to execute a command by double-clicking on a *starter* on my Ubuntu Lucid desktop. More specifically, I would like to start a `rdesktop` session. I have thus entered

`rdesktop -u user -d domain address.to.remote.server`

into the *Command* field of the starter.  However, double clicking does nothing, even though the starter is set to *executable*. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Open a terminal and run `tail -n0 -f ~/.xsession-errors` just before you double click the launcher icon. Watch for error messages appearing when double clicking.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the hint on checking the `.xsession-errors` log, I was able to solve my own question. As a matter of fact, I realized that the `%` sign in

```
rdesktop -u user -d domain -g 90% address.to.remote.server
```

is required to be escaped by a `%%` as in `-g 90%%`. Strangely, this is not necessary if the command is entered directly in the shell.